# Why does an ellipsis have three dots?

Tags: etymology, punctuation, writing-style, ellipses

It might be an odd question, but I'm trying to comprehend why do we use three dots in an ellipsis. Wouldn't two dots suffice? An ellipsis serves a dual purpose, it can be used to either denote an unfinished thought or omitted words, but why is it written using three dots? Have we any meaning assigned to two, horizontally aligned dots?

In some programming languages two dots are used to specify ranges, i.e. all integer numbers between 1 and 9 (including both) may be described as 1..9, which is perfectly distinguishable from 1.9, as in "one point nine".

I have stumbled upon [a question](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/12/two-dots-or-three.html) on this topic and the answer suggests that *Oxford English Dictionary* uses double dots instead of triple dots because it shortens the contents considerably. If that is the case, why do we even bother with triple dots?

Comment: One extra dot can be a typo. When you get the third, then you have a reasonable assurance it was intentional.

Comment: That is some explanation, but hardly convincing. Applying this logic would undermine double letter spelling. I mean, why spelling and not spellling?

Comment: you can't pronounce spellling.  The ellipsis is a typographic symbol, not a word or part of a word.  Their requirements are quite different.  The main need for an ellipsis is to *not be missed when reading*

Comment: While I agree that punctuation has a different role in a language than spelling, I am still not convinced. I will refer to my previous example, 1.9 is quite distinguishable from 1..9, do we really need to emphasize with 1...9?

Comment: In fact, there's also a four-dot ellipsis used in abridged quotations to indicate that an entire sentence has been skipped. And some languages (Japanese & Chinese for certain; perhaps others) use a six-dot ellipsis.

Comment: @Oldcat And before mechanical printing devices...? Although if we're talking about not missing something when reading, I agree three dots are easier to distinguish than two (as in the case of bad eyesight, or on this phone's screen. ;)

Comment: @Rusty Tuba I am aware of the four dotted version, but adding a bit of space in between would not hurt the message; if I were to write "... ." it would communicate that I have omitted the end of the sentence altogether. But the question remains, why not ".. ."?

Comment: Yes, the question remains. I did some digging around and couldn't find a good answer. Certainly these things sometimes evolve in less than perfectly rational ways. I mean, I doubt that three dots were used because one extra dot could be a typo. For a very long time punctuation was a freestyle sport. When certain conventions were widely adopted it wasn't the result of a symposium of learned linguists, stylists and/or typographers. I remain keen to see if someone provides a good historical answer.

Comment: @Oldcat I feeel reasssured now.

Comment: @Oldcat \\ My father, for some reason, did not like the name Donald; so, I was named Donn. Back then, it was rare; nowadays, my perception is that I cannot walk five blocks without tripping over a Donn. I am considering adding a third n, just to maintain my leadership in the field.

Comment: Because typesetters only had so many periods, and they didn't want to waste them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best answer as to why we use a three-dot ellipsis can be found in the book [The Motivated Sign (Iconicity in Language and Literature)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1588110036), but allow me to explain briefly.

*ellipsis* is derived from the Greek *elleipein* essentially meaning "to fall short" or "leave behind." The Viking language of Old Norse was [one of the first known languages to use the ellipses](http://books.google.com/books?id=HwwJAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA107&ots=GCa98C6D9E&dq=old%20norse%20ellipses&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=old%20norse%20ellipses&f=false), albeit without the specific "..." notation. In Old Norse, these *ellipses* were literally omissions of infinitive phrases and non-action verbs.

It wasn't until 1588 that [the three-dot ellipses first appeared](http://books.google.com/books?id=vrgleuy9iMEC&lpg=PA17&ots=XKvCn01_Qf&dq=The%20Motivated%20Sign&pg=PA141#v=onepage&q=andria%20by%20maurice&f=false) in print in Maurice Kyffin's translation of *[Andria by Terence](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/22188/22188-0.txt)*. It is unlikely we will ever know why three dots were chosen over any other possible symbol or series of symbols. However, this precedence combined with arbitrary rule probably has brought us to today's modern usage guidelines of the ellipsis.

Comment: The link regarding first appearance is interesting, though, because the picture/figure it references shows various versions of ellipses within the same document, including dashes for dots.

Comment: Old Norse does not "use the ellipses". You can see quite clearly in the example sentences that there is no particular symbol used, nor even any symbol at all. The words are just dropped. This is [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), which is something else entirely: It is the omission of unnecessary words, which is a very, very common feature of language.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the example you provide for programming languages is not completely correct.

Most modern programming languages use the 3 dot ellipsis for specifying variable numbers of parameters in a function. The two dot ellipsis IS used in some older languages to specify a range, but now it is less common. Some differentiate, using the 3 dot ellipsis to omit the last value, and the 2 dot ellipsis to include it. In system design, the two dot ellipsis is used to specify ranges.

Coming back to your question regarding why we DON'T use the two dot ellipsis, it seems to be more of a standard. Wikipedia says that 18th and 19th century writers used the ellipsis to indicate a blank to be filled like this:

> Jan was born on . . . Street in Warsaw.

Where the ellipsis denoted missing data. With this in mind, I guess it could be said that 3 dots took up more space, allowing larger words to be written in the space. Not sure, but maybe it was something of the sort.

So, it seems that the 3 dot ellipsis is used, since the ellipsis originated in that form (perhaps due to practical reasons such as the one I mentioned), and because it is maintained as a standard in that form.

Answer (score 1):

An Ellipse, in mathematics, has three co-linear points of importance; a center and, on either side, a focus.  So, in an Ellipse, we have three dots in a row [focus, center, focus]...hence the name ellipsis.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. That's all good and well, but *ellipsis* did not derive from *ellipse*, so it seems a coincidence at best. Can you present a reference or authority which asserts this connection? I also encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.